# Disable auto-adjusting of font size in group bar chart in plotlyjs

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I am trying to plot the data as on the figure below, The bar width is small, so Plotly makes the font smaller for two-digit and three-digit numbers. How to disable or control this.

[image]

I do have textfont set with:

```
textposition: 'outside',
textfont: {
    color: 'black',
    size: 14
},
```

but these settings are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try this option [constraintext](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/bar/#bar-constraintext) set to `none` :

```js
    textposition: 'outside',
    textfont: {
        color: 'black',
        size: 14
    },
    width: 0.25,
    constraintext: 'none',
```

This option can be used to limit the size of text inside or outside a bar so that it is no larger than the bar itself, or to remove this constraint. (can take the following values: "inside" | "outside" | "both" | "none" [default: "both"] )

Comment: Why? What does `constraintext` do? Add the explanation in your answer. Don't just post a link to the docs. The link can become dead or useless in the future.